# Grouping task so that one email will be sent for the group of task

Tags: tasks

I need to group all the task assigned to one person. This could be 50 task assigned at one time. At which point I want to alert the task owner that they have all these task assigned to them as well as a reminders through a workflow.

I have the workflow written but I can seem to find a way to group the tasks so that only one email for the group of task is sent and not 50 emails, one for each task.